# How to correctly apply MethodResponse to "filter" AWS api gateway response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

When trying to apply MethodResponse template I am failing to see any difference in final response. My goal is to successfully apply schema with minItems and maxItems for array property.

Example response from lambda method:

```
{
  "_id": "5d5110f52e8b560af82dec69",
  "index": 0,
  "friends": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Mcconnell Pugh"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Peggy Caldwell"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jocelyn Mccarthy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema I have tried to apply in MethodResponse:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Empty Schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "friends" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "minItems" : 1,
        "maxItems" : 2,
        "items" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type" : "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "index" : {
        "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect to see only two "friends" in final response, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

After long research and a lot of AWS documentations I have found that:

1. It support JSON Schema 4, however not all features are supported -> related [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html)
2. Method Response basically does not apply validation. In my understanding, it just bring use if you want to export your API to Swagger to have well described specs -> related [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-response.html) last Paragraph is important

So final answer to my question would be - you just cannot use Method Response as a filter, that's not the purpose of it.